# Section addresses goes beyond the image region - Intel Pin

Tags: elf, intel-pin

I developed a simple pintool to list all the sections of the program's main executable image (iterating over all of its sections), and also its low and high limits using `IMG_HighAddress` and `IMG_LowAddress`; according to Pin, these return the definite limits of the image.

To my surprise, the sections went way beyond the low and high limits reported by these functions. Have I done something wrong, or are these functions inaccurate?

My image load function:

```
VOID ImageLoad(IMG img, VOID *v)
{

if (!IMG_IsMainExecutable(img))
    return;

ADDRINT mainExeImageLowAddr = IMG_LowAddress(img);
ADDRINT mainExeImageHighAddr = IMG_HighAddress(img);    

cout << "Image limits " << hex << mainExeImageLowAddr << " - " << mainExeImageHighAddr << endl;

for (SEC sec = IMG_SecHead(img); SEC_Valid(sec); sec = SEC_Next(sec))
{   
    cout << "Section " << SEC_Name(sec) << " at addresses 0x" << hex << SEC_Address(sec) << " - 0x" << SEC_Address(sec)+SEC_Size(sec)-1 << endl;
}

}
```

The results for running it on /bin/ls:

```
Image limits 400000 - 418b23
Section .interp at addresses 0x400200 - 0x40021b
Section .note.ABI-tag at addresses 0x40021c - 0x40023b
Section .note.gnu.build-id at addresses 0x40023c - 0x40025f
Section .dynsym at addresses 0x4002c8 - 0x400eaf
Section .rela.dyn at addresses 0x401618 - 0x4017c7
Section .rela.plt at addresses 0x4017c8 - 0x402157
Section .init at addresses 0x402158 - 0x40216f
Section .plt at addresses 0x402170 - 0x4027df
Section .text at addresses 0x4027e0 - 0x412347
Section .fini at addresses 0x412348 - 0x412355
Section .rodata at addresses 0x412360 - 0x415e86
Section .eh_frame_hdr at addresses 0x415e88 - 0x41653b
Section .eh_frame at addresses 0x416540 - 0x41851b
Section .dynstr at addresses 0x41851c - 0x418b23
Section .ctors at addresses 0x619000 - 0x61900f
Section .dtors at addresses 0x619010 - 0x61901f
Section .jcr at addresses 0x619020 - 0x619027
Section .data.rel.ro at addresses 0x619040 - 0x619a87
Section .dynamic at addresses 0x619a88 - 0x619c57
Section .got at addresses 0x619c58 - 0x619cef
Section .got.plt at addresses 0x619cf0 - 0x61a037
Section .data at addresses 0x61a040 - 0x61a23f
Section .bss at addresses 0x61a240 - 0x61af5f
Section .gnu.conflict at addresses 0x61af60 - 0x61b6f7
Section .gnu_debuglink at addresses 0x0 - 0xf
Section .gnu.prelink_undo at addresses 0x0 - 0x8ff
Section .shstrtab at addresses 0x0 - 0x12d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have I done something wrong

Not necessarily.

It looks like Pin is trying to map ELF concepts to Windows-specific concepts, and there isn't a one-to-one mapping.

Intel [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/65163/Pin/html/group__IMG__BASIC__API.html#g6eff113bda0343f46397fe9cc866d5df) for `IMG_HighAddress` says:

```
Tells the highest address of any code or data loaded by the image.
This is the address of the last byte loaded by the image.
```

But what exactly does that mean?

ELF image loading is defined by `PT_LOAD` segments. You can see the segments, as well as section-to-segment mapping, in output from `readelf -Wl a.out`.

Usually there will be two `LOAD` segments: one with `r-x` protections covering `.text`, `.rodata`, and other read-only sections, and a second with `rw-` protections, covering `.data`, `.bss` and other writable sections.

It looks (from your output) like `IMG_HighAddress` is describing only the first `LOAD` segment.

You should also note that *not all* sections are `LOAD`able, and the non-`LOAD`able sections are usually not covered by any segment (and do not occupy memory at runtime). Various `.debug*` sections are usually not `LOAD`able.

Comment: Notice the remark on the function: `In this case, the function will return the high address of the text segment`. Since Unix images, as you wrote, tend to be split in memory, this almost always happens.